# React Router - BrowserHistory.Push VS. ContextTypes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am finishing up on an advanced react/redux tutorial and came across a part in the course where the instructor uses browserHistory.push to link to a route, as opposed to the previous method used of creating a static class variable called contextTypes and setting it equal to something like React.PropTypes.blah blah blah.

What's the difference between that and using browserHistory.push? browserHistory.push seems a lot easier as a programatic reroute as opposed to setting context types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which tutorials you used, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark.

I suppose you're using something like https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux in your first tutorial that sync the router state with your redux state and have your router object in the context. Then you can do something like:

`this.context.router.push(location)` to dispatch a location change
This will save the location change to your redux state and then load that new route.

At the core react-router-redux (and a lot of other routing libraries) use https://github.com/ReactTraining/history to manage the history of routes navigated to. That allows you to use the HTML5 history API in modern browsers, to fall back to a hashHistory (index.html/#page-one) or a memory history i.e. to render server side.

The history package comes with it's own API. And in your tutorial that `browserHistory.push()` probably calls that API of the history package directly ([see here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation)).

Which will result the app to load the new route, but will probably bypass the sync to your redux store.

Your second tutorial might not use react-router-redux or have a different setup.